# Address family not supported by protocol exception on real android device

Tags: android, sockets, exception, device

I'm having a little trouble here, on one hand I have a server listening on port 23000 and on the other an Android App acting as the client. While connection seems to work in the Emulator (this is built for 2.3.3 by the way) using the typical 10.2....IP, when trying on a Samsung Galaxy Tab I keep on getting the famous:

"Address family not supported by protocol exception"

Eventually, code looks like this:

```
InetSocketAddress inetAddress;

        //this is done to keep backward compatibility prior 2.0.4 release
        if(host == null || host.equals("")) {
            //check if defaultIp is also empty
            if (defaultIPAddress == null || defaultIPAddress.equals(""))
                throw new UnknownHostException();
            //otherwise start listening on defaultIp
            else
            {
                inetAddress = new InetSocketAddress(defaultIPAddress, port);
            }
        }
        //start listening on host
        else
        {
            inetAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        }

        // open the socket channel
        this.channel = SocketChannel.open(inetAddress);
        this.channel.configureBlocking(false);
        this.channel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

It fails when trying to open the socket at

```
this.channel = SocketChannel.open(inetAddress);
```

Needless to say, I have the required permissions in my Manifest, as said previously, this is working fine in the Emulator.

Besides, this is no network issue, both machines are connected to a Wireless Wifi created using a router I have at hand, with no firewalls, proxys, completely open, to put it that way...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Well, I tried in a 2.3.3 device and it works...there must be included in ICS that is breaking my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody lands on this question and is having the same issue, this was caused because I was trying to open the Socket in the same thread of the main Activity. Looks like this is a) not advisable and b) not permitter any longer. Thus, move your connecting code to a separate thread and you should be safe.